# ui-router angularjs prevent scrolling to bottom of page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

ui-router scrolls to bottom of page when changing from one page to another, navigation is via $state.go() or $state.transitionTo()

I tried calling $anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling(); but still it scrolls to bottom of page

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: I don't believe $state.go() does this by default. Are you sure there isn't another mechanism causing the scrolling?

Comment: Here is a link to my plunker https://plnkr.co/pqlhsN 
before clicking on a link scroll to bottom of page and click a link on the top panel

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `autoscroll="false"`. However I can't really help you without some code snippets

```
<div ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>
```

Comment: I added the parameter autoscroll=false without any affect